# codeigniter can only load index(), not any other methods

Tags: php, html, css, apache, codeigniter

I am running into this problem with codeigniter, where it loads the index() page perfectly, but when it comes to any other function, it just throw me an 404 error. Here is a skeleton code :

```
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access alloowed');
Class User extends CI_Controller{
    var $err;

    public function construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        session_start();
        $this->load->database();            
        $this->load->model('User_Model');           
    }

    public function index(){
        if(isset($this->session->userdata['userID'])){
            $this->welcome();
        }else{
            $this->load->view('banner','Login');
            if(isset($this->err)){
                $data["error"] = $this->err;
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }else{
                $this->load->view('login');
            }               
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }

    public function test(){
        echo "Hello World";
    }

    public function welcome(){
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->load->view('banner','Login');
        if(isset($this->err)){
            $data["error"] = $this->err;
            $this->load->view('register',$data);
        }else{
            $this->load->view('register');
        }
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function registration(){
        //registration ops
    }

    public function login(){
        //login ops
}
    }
?>
```

So, when I am trying to navigate to www.example.com/index.php/user , it runs perfect, but when I try to let it run register, or do a login operation, it just throws an 404 error. Is there any solution to this?

Here is a html code generated using with index():

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="http://localhost/baseball/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>



<body>

<div>

  <p><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/cartoon-baseball-player-vector-illustration-30999087.jpg" height="250" alt=""/>Baseball Card Shop</p>

  <hr />

  <p class="loginInfo">

        <a href="shopping cart">Shopping Cart</a>

  </p>

  <hr/>

</div>

 <div class="central_login">

    <div class="main">

        <form action="http://localhost/baseball/index.php/user/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">     <div class="left">

          <p>

            <label for="login"> Login: </label>          

            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" required/>

          </p>

          <p>

            <label for="pwd">Password: </label>

            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" required/>

          </p>

          <p><label id='pwdErr'></label>

            <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="create-account" class="button"/>

        </p>

        </div>

         </form>     <div class="right">

        <form action="http://localhost/baseball/index.php/user/register" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">          <p>Not our customer, worry not ! Register here, it is free!</p>

            <input type="submit" value="Register HERE!" id="register" class="button"/> 

        </form>  </div>

         </div>

</div>

<footer>

  <p>CSC309 Assignment</p>

  <p>Baseball Web Application</p>

</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: does your this url works? www.example.com/index.php?/user/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your .htaccess. The following .htaccess will help you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And need to change the following configure in config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file at my root folder of the web application, it doesn't work ...

Comment: Hi, it actually works, but $config['index_page'] = 'Index.php';

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are drawing attention in your code:

First, the use of **var** key word. It was used to declare class members in php4.

It is deprecated in php5 and greater version.

It will work. But raise a warning and is a bad practice.

Second. From the code you have posted, I believe, you have not auto loaded Session library.

Change the session_start() code in your constructor to :

```
$this->library->load('session');
```

Third thing I noted is this line of code:

```
$this->load->view('banner','Login');
```

The view functions of the loader class takes parameters in the below format.

```
$this->load->view('file_name', $data, true/false);
```

The syntax that you are might not be correct.

If you are planning to load banner and login file, you should do this:

```
$this->load->view('banner');
$this->load->view('Login');
```

On a side note, using native php sessions and CI sessions might be confusing and also may raise conflict in some situations.